# How do I access nested arrays from a json_decode in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have spent hours at this and I've read loads of answers here on stackoverflow and none have helped.

All I've been able to do so far is to print **Market Square - Clifden** for this example.

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
$obj = $obj[0];
print $obj->{'title'};
```

I can't figure out how to access "name" nested inside "image" so I can get **market_square_clifden.jpg**.

I'd be grateful for some pointers.

```
array(1){
        [0]=>array(12){
            ["_id"]=>array(1){
                ["$oid"]=>string(24)"51f674e4e4b0066cc8197033"
            }
            ["display"]=>int(1)
            ["title"]=>string(23)"Market Square - Clifden"
            ["class"]=>string(21)"market_square_clifden"
            ["icon"]=>string(16)"camera_small.png"
            ["image"]=>array(4){
                ["name"]=>string(25)"market_square_clifden.jpg"
                ["top"]=>string(16)"7.98958587646484"
                ["left"]=>string(18)"397.98614501953125"
                ["maxwidth"]=>string(16)"599.777777671814"
            }
            ["locs"]=>array(2){
                ["lng"]=>float(-10.022516)
                ["lat"]=>float(53.488111)
            }
            ["pov"]=>array(3){
                ["heading"]=>string(17)"-14.1950626239811"
                ["pitch"]=>string(18)"-6.368221166504443"
                ["zoom"]=>string(18)"0.8399999999999999"
            }
            ["photo"]=>array(3){
                ["takenby"]=>string(13)"Robert French"
                ["sentinby"]=>string(34)"The Lawrence Photograph Collection"
                ["description"]=>string(263)"Clifden (Irish: An Clochán, meaning 'stepping stones' is a town on the coast of County Galway, Ireland and being Connemara's largest town, it is often referred to as 'the Capital of Connemara'. It is located on the Owenglen River where it flows into Clifden Bay."
            }
            ["date"]=>array(2){
                ["posted"]=>string(53)"Mon Jul 29 2013 14:53:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)"
                ["circa"]=>string(9)"1880-1900"
            }
            ["comments"]=>array(1){
                [0]=>array(2){
                    ["poster"]=>string(0)""
                    ["comment"]=>string(0)""
                }
            }
            ["tags"]=>array(1){
                [0]=>array(2){
                    ["name"]=>string(0)""
                    ["slug"]=>string(0)""
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same way you access them in native structures. Since you now have a native structure.

Comment: Nobody will be able to figure out your odd variable dump. See [array/json traversal](http://array.include-once.org/)

Comment: thanks for reformatting, I was just doing it after mario's advice

Comment: Who not ``$obj = json_decode($data, true);`` and ``print $obj[0]['image']['name']``?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the commenters mentioned, please fix your variable formatting - it helps get answers more quickly.

Assuming you are using default `json_decode` settings, each JSON object will become a PHP object. (See [the json_decode documentation](https://www.php.net/json_decode%20the%20PHP%20documentation.) at php.net.)

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
$obj = $obj[0];
// title attribute
$obj->title
// image object
$obj->image
// image name
$obj->image->name
```

If you force everything to be associative arrays:

```
$obj = json_decode($data,true);
$obj = $obj[0];
// title attribute
$obj['title']
// image object
$obj['image']
// image name
$obj['image']['name']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get it using the code below.  You can think of all arrays as dictionaries or associated arrays in php.  Either They are indexed by numbers (regular array) or they are indexed by keys (associated arrays).

```
$obj[0]["image"]["name"]
```

In the instance of nested arrays, when you access the inner array, you can treat that as if it were an array.  Think of it like this:

```
$innerArray = $obj[0];
// The image key gives us an array as well.
$image = $innerArray["image"];
// Now we have the dictionary where the name is
$name = $image["name"];
```