# Need to remove numeric keys in php array

Tags: php, json

Below is my php array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [requests] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [requests] => 44
        )
    [overview_chart_data] => Array
        (
            [response] => ok
        )
)
```

below is php json encoded result of above array ,

```
{"0":{"requests":22},"1":{"requests":44},"overview_chart_data":{"response":"ok"}},
```

for some reason  I need to get the result like below,

```
{{"requests":22},{"requests":44},"overview_chart_data":{"response":"ok"}}
```

Is it possible to get by expected result..! Anyhelp Appreciated...

Comment: _...Is it possible to get by expected result.._ Yes it is! What have you tried for that?

Comment: You will never get such json with associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom script for that:

```
<?php
$a = [
    ['requests' => 22],
    ['requests' => 44],
    'overview_chart_data' => ['response' => 'ok']
];
$output = [];
foreach ($a as $k => $v)
    $output[] = (is_string($k) ? ('"' . $k . '":') : '') . json_encode($v);

echo '{' . implode(',', $output) . '}' . PHP_EOL;
```

**But it is not a valid JSON document.**

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a good S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644977/3794876) to help you get these results by doing this...

```
$testArray = array(
    (object)array("name" => "John", "hobby" => "hiking"),
    (object)array("name" => "Jane", "hobby" => "dancing")
);

echo "Person 1 Name: ".$testArray[0]->name;
echo "Person 2 Hobby: ".$testArray[1]->hobby;
```

This will give you the desired outcome of having objects in an array without numerical indices... however a much more proper way would be to [follow this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22278545/3794876) instead. This way you can use the correct JSON decoding procedures to capture the ability to do this kind of easy syntax `$obj = json_decode($data);`.

Answer (score 1):

try using $array = array_values($array); That will achieve what you are looking for without too much hassle